# Get og:image URL from LPLinkMetadata instead of UIImage data

Tags: ios, swift5, ipados

I am able to get `UIImage` from `NSItemProvider` of `LPLinkMetadata` from the below code.

**But I need the URL of the remote image.
How do I do that?**

I believe `LPLinkMetadata` is derived from **OpenGraph** headers `og:image` which is an URL for the image.

```
metadata?.imageProvider?.loadFileRepresentation(
     forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypeImage as String, 
     completionHandler: { (url, imageProviderError) in
         if imageProviderError != nil {
            return
         }
         let myImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: (url?.path)!)
     })
```